# php program to read <somename>.sql file and auto generate table and insert data in MySQL database?

Tags: php

php program to read  .sql file and auto generate table and insert data in MySQL database? 
(i export all the database table..sql i want a php program which read the .sql file and auto generate all the table and insert data into it..)

thanks in advance..

Comment: You want us to write the code for you ?

Comment: If you want it, write it. What's your question about it?

Comment: Use file_get_contents(filename.sql) to get content from file

Comment: Smells like homework assignment to me

Comment: why the hell don't you just use phpMyAdmin or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
<?php
    if(isset($_FILE["file"])){ 
        $dshost = "";
        $dsdatabase = "";
        $dsusername = "";
        $dspassword = "";
        $connection1 = mysql_connect($dshost,$dsusername,$dspassword);
        $seldb = mysql_select_db($dsdatabase, $connection1) or die( "Unable to select database");
        $sql = file_get_contents($_FILE['file']);
        $q=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
        if($q){
            echo "Success!";
        }else{
            echo "Fail.";
        }
    }else{
        ?>
        <form action="upload_file.php" method="post"
        enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label for="file">Filename:</label>
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
        <?php 
    }
?>
```

I think I did that right. Except people will yell at me if I don't tell you to use PDO or mysqli instead. obviously you need to add your own sql creds at the top.

Comment: Adelphia, i use ur concept to read the .sql file and explode and fetch the sql statement and then execute.. (thank u)

Comment: mysql functions are indeed deprecated and would strongly suggest using PDO.

Answer (score 2):

Try below library, it will help you to upload .sql file and execute it's content

http://www.ozerov.de/bigdump/

Answer (score 0):

ok here it is, if you know even little bit about programming you'll understand else you need to goto school. this is command and data to make tables

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wp_options` (
  `option_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `option_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
  `option_value` longtext NOT NULL,
  `autoload` varchar(20) NOT NULL default 'yes',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`option_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `option_name` (`option_name`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=151 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

and below is data, please note that it is just example, we are not gonna do exactly what you want to do but we can help you get started.

```
INSERT INTO `wp_options` VALUES (1, 'siteurl', 'http://www.lostknowledge.org', 'yes');
INSERT INTO `wp_options` VALUES (2, 'blogname', 'Lost Knowledge', 'yes');
INSERT INTO `wp_options` VALUES (3, 'blogdescription', 'Just another WordPress site', 'yes');
INSERT INTO `wp_options` VALUES (4, 'users_can_register', '0', 'yes');
INSERT INTO `wp_options` VALUES (5, 'admin_email', '8156345@gmail.com', 'yes');
INSERT INTO `wp_options` VALUES (6, 'start_of_week', '1', 'yes');
INSERT INTO `wp_options` VALUES (7, 'use_balanceTags', '0', 'yes');
INSERT INTO `wp_options` VALUES (8, 'use_smilies', '1', 'yes');
INSERT INTO `wp_options` VALUES (9, 'require_name_email', '1', 'yes');
INSERT INTO `wp_options` VALUES (10, 'comments_notify', '1', 'yes');
INSERT INTO `wp_options` VALUES (11, 'posts_per_rss', '10', 'yes');
INSERT INTO `wp_options` VALUES (12, 'rss_use_excerpt', '0', 'yes');
INSERT INTO `wp_options` VALUES (13, 'mailserver_url', 'mail.example.com', 'yes');
```

given the question that you want to use it from file you can use &sql = file_get_contents(filename.sql) and harki krishnan told and then insert $sql after command create table if not exists